# Anyone able to use Swift SMART FHIR with iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, hl7-fhir, aerogear

I have been having a terrible time trying to figure out the OAUTH process for an iOS app into the Allscripts FHIR sandbox. I was hoping to use SMART SWIFT (https://github.com/smart-on-fhir/Swift-SMART) as it seems to handle this login, but I keep getting errors. The latest is after loading the CocoaPod and opening the workspace, just getting an error that there is no MODULE NAMED SMART.

Has anyone been able to successfully implement this pod, or does anyone have recommendations on how to setup the OAUTH? I am pretty new on iOS and trying to learn this piece, but have not found anything that great with the latest Swift.

Would love any help or pointing in the right direction for some good training on doing OAUTH 2on a thirp part app.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this into your podfile so that you'll get the latest build with all the submodules directly from the git repo.

pod 'SMART', :git => 'https://github.com/smart-on-fhir/Swift-SMART.git'

SMART relies on a few other frameworks that the author created, and it seems like the version on Cocoapods doesn't pull those in automatically.